# Sharing Pi's internet with a router

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-squeeze

I've got the following setup:

1. Pi3 connected to my ISP's router via eth0 and assigned a static IP of 192.168.69.89
2. There is OpenVPN client configured and running on Pi. This bit is
   working fine.
3. There is another ethernet interface on Pi - eth1 and
   it is connected to a second router.
4. I want to connect devices to that second router which would securely connect to internet using Pi's connection (which goes through VPN).

So Pi's IP is 69.89. I have tried setting up eth1 with 70.1 and configuring second router with 70.2 and set the dhcp settings on that router to assign IPs in the range of 70.3 to 70.100, but obviously I have no clue what I am doing. Second router is up and running, assigning IPs successfully. The issue is that my second router doesn't have an internet connection. I have tried following this guide - https://github.com/arpitjindal97/raspbian-recipes (wifi to eth route, of course changing the variables in the script from wlan to eth0, and eth0 to eth1 to reflect my setup) to share internet between eth0 and eth1 but didn't have any luck. Can anyone please let me know how and what should I set up in order for second router to have an internet connection? Thank you.

Comment: How does your pi have 2 ethernet connections from only 1 port?

Comment: It can have 5 in total, I guess. Unless the USB->RJ45 adapters work with USB hubs as well.